# How to get file ID on upload of a file using Google Drive API with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I am using the "nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive" package for Laravel to use Google Drive as a filesystem and store files.

I also need to call these files and show them, but since Google drive doesn't allow searching by name and only a unique ID, is there a way to get the file ID of the uploaded file from Google Drive.

this is the code I use to upload a file on google drive -

```
\Storage::disk('google')->put($file_name, file_get_contents($file));
```

This returns a boolean true and false but I need the file ID so I can store it and call the specific file when required. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you already scripted a PHP Drive API code and you only need to get the new file ID. If my understanding of your question is correct, then you can manage it very easily. After uploading a file using [`Files.create()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), you will get a [`files` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) as a response. In the resource you can find the `id` property of the generated file. Please ask me any doubts about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code after uploading file:

```
$details = \Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file ID using:

```php
Storage::disk("google")->put($path, $contents);
$meta = Storage::disk("google")
->getAdapter()
->getMetadata($path)
->extraMetadata()['id];
```